# MFP 7.1 version Adapter Preview button is not visible

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-console

MFP 7.1 version with Liberty profile.After runtime deployment we have added few adapter. Unable to see PREVIEW button under common Resources menu. Is this feature has removed from MFP 7.1 version?. If not then what is the setting to enable this preview options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a preview button in server deployments (= outside of the development server in CLI or Eclipse). This has been the case since 6.3.